# stop application in tomcat7 for sure

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, raspbian

I am running tomcat on my Raspberry Pi. When I go to manager and stop unwanted apps (/, /docs, /examples) these apps are stopped. But when I reboot my Rasbian (Debian on RPi) server all apps are restarted as well. I want to leave selected apps stopped for sure (concurrently I don't want these stopped apps completely delete, maybe in the future I will need it).

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat will always autostart these apps if they are inside the webapps folder. Simply move them to another one, for later use.

Answer (score 0):

I did this

```
sudo mv /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/docs.xml /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/docs.xml
sudo mv /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/examples.xml /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/examples.xml

sudo mv /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/index.html /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/__index.html
sudo nano /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/index.html (save blank file)
```

That's it! :)